# rm: cannot remove : No such file or directory

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ls

[image]

but the file clearly exists and I can open the contents in it, just the 'link' field is 0 when trying ls -Al, so I couldn't delete it,

I am using  Ubuntu app from the Windows 10 store

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The Windows Subsystem for Linux Version 1 does not have its own kernel so it's still dependent on Windows for memory usage, disk usage, ... whereas having an Ubuntu running on a native Linux kernel, **there is no issue with deleting open files!**  if you `sudo rm --force somefile`

### the file will be deleted! :-)

Ubuntu running under WSL V1 still uses the Windows kernel with a translation layer in-between Ubuntu and Windows so you need to close all the applications / users that access the file as otherwise you get errors that actually don't mean anything like:

> rm: cannot remove : No such file or directory

(which solved your issue)  **0:-)**

In Ubuntu running under WSL V2, it depends:

- If running an application on a Linux file system like EXT4: no issues
- If running applications in the Windows File system (aka `NTFS`): *Windows errors still apply*

[Relevant XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/149/):

[image: sudo make ma a sandwich]

Comment: +1 for explaining sudo with comic

Answer (score 2):

I closed all the editors accessing the directory and deleted it from windows and it worked...

Comment: Just [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1161445/revisions) my answer to make that clearer...